# Magento 1.8 - Edit sales/order/view/order_id/2222/ template

Tags: magento-1.8, php, template

I'm working on a magento ecommerce and i need to change the template inside of the red square ( [See Picture](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=189c062) )

Location of frontend design: app/design/tiffosi/default/template/

What is the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look on

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/sales/order/info.phtml
```

and

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/payment/info/default.phtml
```

In order to customize them you need to copy them to your theme, in your case

```
app/design/tiffosi/default/template/sales/order/info.phtml
```

and

```
app/design/tiffosi/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml
```

Comment: I've already tried to write something (like test) in info.phtml but withou any changes on frontend....even after clean all cache.

I'll take a look in that payment/info/default.phtml

Comment: You may find this extension useful for developing purposes: 

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints

It should point you to the correct template file.